# How to Loadbalance a Postgres BDR Cluster

Tags: postgresql, high-availability, postgresql-bdr

I'm planning to use BDR (by 2ndQuadrant) to setup a multi master cluster for my PostgreSQL Databases. how can i achieve real loadbalancing for read and write Operations? I dont want to do it on the application side.

Is it a good idea to combine pgpool and a BDR Cluster, given that pgpool seems to be able to Balance only Select-Queries or is there a better way to distribute load over the whole cluster?

Answer (score 3):

No it's bad idea to combine BDR with pgpool.

Instead this you can use HAProxy load balancer which have various ACL rules which can be configured for your BDR cluster.